# Guardar PHP si todos los campos estan completos

Tags: php, html, formularios, post

Tengo un simple formulario html y un codigo php que checkea que todos los campos obligatorios estan completos. Si todos estan correctos los guardan en un archivo .txt, si no lo estan muestra un mensaje de error.

Mi pregunta es como hacer que solo guarde los datos en el .txt si todos los campos son correctos.

Mi idea fue hacer un contador, donde sume 1 cada vez que se genera un error

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$fail = 0;
if (empty($_POST["producto"])) {
    $prodErr ="Ingrese nombre de producto";
    $fail++;
} 
else {
    $producto = ($_POST["producto"]);
}
if (empty($_POST["cantidad"])) {
    $cantErr ="Ingrese cantidad del producto";
    $fail++;
} 
elseif ($_POST["cantidad"] < 99) {
    $cantidad = ($_POST["cantidad"]);
}
else {
    $cantErr ="Ingrese una cantidad valida 1-99";
    $fail++;
}
if (empty($_POST["precComp"])) {
    $precCompErr ="Ingrese un número";
    $fail++;
} 
else {
    $precComp = ($_POST["precComp"]);
}
if (empty($_POST["precVent"])) {
    $precVentErr ="Ingrese un número";
    $fail++;
} 
else {
    $precVent = ($_POST["precVent"]);
}
if ($fail == 0) {
        fwrite($myfile, "Producto: " .$producto. PHP_EOL ."Cantidad: ".$cantidad. PHP_EOL ."Precio Compra: " .$precComp. PHP_EOL  ."Precio Venta: " .$precVent);
        fclose($myfile);

    }       
else {}
```

Luego con sentencia IF si el contador es 0 guarda los datos en el .txt, ELSE no hace nada.

Esto no esta funcionando, si envio el formulario en blanco, o con algun dato en falta me da el error de que Ingrese una cantidad pero el archivo se modifica.

¿Se puede solucionar?
¿Que otra forma hay para hacer esto?
Gracias

Comment: Buenas, la primera falta que veo es que no tienes un [fopen](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 0):

veo que no tienes la función [fopen](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php), por otro lado, el tema de la validación yo lo haría así:

```
$fail = false;
$producto = null;
$cantidad = null;
$precComp = null;
$precVent = null;
$errors = [];
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["producto"])) {
    $errors[]="Ingrese nombre de producto";
    $fail=true;
} 
else {
    $producto = ($_POST["producto"]);
}
if (empty($_POST["cantidad"])) {
    $errors[] ="Ingrese cantidad del producto";
    $fail=true;
} 
elseif ($_POST["cantidad"] < 99) {
    $cantidad = ($_POST["cantidad"]);
}
else {
    $errors[] ="Ingrese una cantidad valida 1-99";
    $fail=true;
}
if (empty($_POST["precComp"])) {
    $errors[] ="Ingrese un número";
    $fail=true;
} 
else {
    $precComp = ($_POST["precComp"]);
}
if (empty($_POST["precVent"])) {
    $errors[] ="Ingrese un número";
    $fail=true;
} 
else {
    $precVent = ($_POST["precVent"]);
}
if (!$fail) {
    fopen($myfile, "a");
    fwrite($myfile, "Producto: " .$producto. PHP_EOL ."Cantidad: ".$cantidad. PHP_EOL ."Precio Compra: " .$precComp. PHP_EOL  ."Precio Venta: " .$precVent);

    fclose($myfile);

    }       
else {
   echo var_dump(errors);
}
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: Perfecto, me encanto. El signo ! significa que guarde el archivo si $fail es false, correcto?

Comment: @GastonRaboy exactamente